# Fixing newlines within CSV with perl Text::CSV_XS

Tags: perl, csv

I'm trying to cleanup some csv files which have no escaping.

I have no perl experience but scraping a few lines of code together from the examples of Text::CSV_XS i managed to get a working script, except for non escaped newlines.

https://gist.github.com/samvdb/761d12cb6e0275105a689ce25765496d

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# This script can be used as a base to parse unreliable CSV streams
# Modify to your own needs
#
#      (m)'08 [23 Apr 2008] Copyright H.M.Brand 2008-2018

use strict;
use warnings;

sub usage {
    my $err = shift and select STDERR;
    print <<"EOH";
usage: $0 [-o file] [-s S] [file]
    -o F  --out=F     output to file F (default STDOUT)
    -s S  --sep=S     set input separator to S (default ; , TAB or |)
EOH
    exit $err;
} # usage

use Getopt::Long qw(:config bundling);
GetOptions (
    "help|?"        => sub { usage (0); },
    "s|sep=s"       => \my $in_sep,
    "o|out=s"       => \my $opt_o,
    ) or usage (1);

use Text::CSV_XS qw( csv );

my $io  = shift || \*DATA;
my $eol = "\n";

binmode STDOUT, ":encoding(utf-8)";

my @hdr;
my @opt_i = (
    in  => $io,
    binary             => 1,
    blank_is_undef     => 1,
    allow_loose_quotes => 1,
    allow_loose_escapes => 1,
    sep => ";",
    encoding => "utf16le",
    );

my @opt_o = (out => \*STDOUT, eol => $eol, sep => ",", quo => '"',             always_quote  => 1,);


push @opt_i,
    bom          => 1,
    sep_set      => [ $in_sep ],
    keep_headers => \@hdr;
push @opt_o,
    headers      => \@hdr;

csv (in => csv (@opt_i), @opt_o);

__END__
a;b;c;d;e;f
"test"and also newline\nhere or something";2;3;4;5;6
"this happens also! "\n here or something";2;3;4;5;6
2;3;4;5;6;7
3;4;5;6;7;8
4;5;6;7;8;9
```

example input:

```
a;b;c;d;e;f
"test"and also newline\nhere or something";2;3;4;5;6
"this happens also! "\n here or something";2;3;4;5;6
2;3;4;5;6;7
3;4;5;6;7;8
4;5;6;7;8;9
```

Expected result for line:

```
"test""and also newline<br/>here or something";2;3;4;5;6
"this happens also! ""<br/> here or something";2;3;4;5;6
```

Can someone help me fix this perl script so the replacement of \n to 
 happens?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please [edit] your post and add the (relevant) code here? Linking to off-site code doesn't help much with giving good answers.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to parse the data without `Text::CSV` if your separation character (';') never needs to be escaped, and the number of columns in your rows are constant. Then you could clean it up as needed. However, you would need to know some Perl to clean up the cells as per your specific needs.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# slurp file into a string and split it
open my $fh,'<',$ARGV[0];
$/ = undef;
my @data = split ';', <$fh>;

my $columns = 6;
my @new_data;

# splice 6 elements from the array at a time until the array is out of elements
while (@data) {
    my @row = splice @data, 0, $columns;
    for my $cell (@row) {
        # inspect / clean up $cell 
    }
    push @new_data, \@row; 
}

for my $row (@new_data) {
    print join(';', @$row)."\n"; 
}
```

Not that this will preserve all newlines in `$cell`, including at the end of each row.

Comment: Hi beasy, this is actually a nice solution since i am sure about how many columns a specific file has. However ; is not escaped so splitting on that character will not cause correct behaviour. 

A very difficult line might be: "foo";"b"\nar";";"foobar"\n

Yes... "b"\nar";"; is 1 column... How can anyone fix that?

Comment: It may not be possible, unless you can identify some kind of pattern that lets you distinguish between columns

Answer (score 0):

Your sample input looks like malformed csv -- I don't think what you listed can be parsed into proper CSV.  For example:

```
"test"and also newline\nhere or something";2;3;4;5;6
"this happens also! "\n here or something";2;3;4;5;6
```

The "quotes" around data indicates everything contained therein may have special characters (the delimiter, newline character, etc), but when you close the quote here:

```
"test"and also newline\nhere or something";2;3;4;5;6
     ^
```

You break that.  To embed a quote, you would need to put two quotes.  This would be properly formed:

```
"test""and also newline\nhere or something";2;3;4;5;6
```

Assuming the actual (rendered) text was `test" and also...`

If I understand what you are trying to do -- replace newline characters with an HTML break, I think this would do the trick:

```
use Text::CSV_XS qw(csv);

my @rows;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({
  binary => 1,
  auto_diag => 1,
  sep_char => ';'
});

open my $IN, '<:encoding(utf8)', "test.csv" or die;
open my $OUT, '>:encoding(utf8)', "new.csv" or die;
while (my $row = $csv->getline($IN)) {
  s/\n/<br>/g for @$row;
  $csv->print ($OUT, $row);
  print $OUT "\n";
}
close $OUT;
close $IN;
```

If this is the sample input:

```
a;b;c;d;e;f
"test""ja ze";2;3;4;5;6
2;3;"This Text has
a newline";5;6;7
3;4;5;6;7;8
4;5;6;7;8;9
```

This would be the output:

```
a;b;c;d;e;f
"test""ja ze";2;3;4;5;6
2;3;"This Text has<br>a newline";5;6;7
3;4;5;6;7;8
4;5;6;7;8;9
```

But again, this all assumes properly formed CSV data.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. Unfortunately, i am dealing with this kind of malformed csv's. I have no control over the source of these files and they do come quoted, but not escaped. Yes... not escaped... I know it's a long shot trying to fix these files..

Comment: Oh wow...  Yeah, that's a different matter.  You probably need to write some code to cleanse the data.  To do this, you need to know a lot about the data -- how many fields, datatypes, etc and derive possible values from that.  I don't envy the task.